# Review of isolated dual power supply circuit for IGBT gate driver

Tags: isolation, gate-driving, igbt

I need to build an isolated power supply for an IGBT gate driver. +15V, -8V.

What I'm trying:
I'm using a 1:1.3 transformer and driving it with a 15V square wave. The output voltage is split 1/3, 2/3, using capacitors. I'm a little uncertain on the theory of this circuit though.

I simulated this circuit with LTSPICE and it seems to be working except I am not getting the voltages that I expect on the output. Spice shows +36V and -18V. I must be doing something wrong but I'm not sure what. The right side is just a resistor/ cap acting as crude model of an igbt gate. And the bottom part generates a pwm with deadtime to drive the gate signals.

What do I change to get +15V and -8V instead of 36/-18?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The transformer switching should be 100KHz not 10Khz but it didn't make a big difference in the simulation.

Comment: Can you zoom in a little? It's not clear if the primary is 34 or 84uH.

Comment: Should be 94u on primary and 158u on secondary. I got the 94u value from the datasheet of the tx, I calculated the 158u

Comment: Key observation: DC current flow G-E is zero.  Why not use a simple regulator (e.g. zener shunt) to set that voltage (plus generous bypass caps), and a total supply of ~23V? Then the driver can be common-ground e.g. IXDD614CI.

Comment: I considered using a shunt regulator. But this IGBT needs a lot of gate drive current. All the shunt resistors I say have a max of 100mA. I'm not sure if that's enough for this IGBT. FF1400R12IP4 is the IGBT.

Comment: I can switch to a center-tap TX if that helps somehow

Comment: Drive current goes through bypass caps, the shunt just needs a mA or whatever to keep it there over the long term.

Comment: I may try that method also Tim. I've built a different gate driver in the past doing exactly that but wasn't sure about the current.

Comment: Just a couple of generic LTspice tips for you.  Select actual diodes instead of using default model `D`.  Also, I'm assuming you set the ESR of the inductors by right-clicking them?  Hard to tell from a screenshot if they're set or not.  And lastly (probably least important), try to use E-sources instead of B-sources whenever possible.  In your case, you should be able to do that since you're only scaling linearly by 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I needed to drive the one leg of the TX with +15/0 and the other leg stays at Vcc/2 using a cap divider. This gets me +18/-9V

[image]